# Possible to sync an activity tracker via bluetooth with Bluestacks?

Tags: bluestacks

It seems like most of the activity trackers coming out will only sync with Android or IOS.  My wife and I do not have smartphones.  Can I get a Bluetooth 4.0 dongle and sync the fitness tracker to my PC using BlueStacks with the Android app?

Answer (score 2):

I did not try it yet, but it seems you can get Bluetooth 4.0 (with the main required feature being called Bluetooth Low Energy or BluetoothLE) by indeed acquiring a Bluetooth 4.0 dongle supporting LE, and then install Android in a virtual machine like VirtualBox or VMWare. This will get you up with a fully featured Android, not with a partial emulator like BlueStacks which is limited by the non-support of Bluetooth in Android debugging tools.

For a step-by-step guide, see this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20348743/bluetooth-low-energy-on-android-emulator/27712017#27712017

Note that the above linked guide is for developpers, in your case there are a few steps that you can probably skip like installing the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-use-the-bluetooth-in-Android-emulators-like-Bluestacks-or-any-other-software

See above link. In short, "NO" you can't. I was wondering the same question, but seems the developers are firm on this feature. However, some fitness devices (Fitbit, or Garmin etc) do have Windows software to sync with their dongle or usb cable.